# Eclipse can't delete lib.jar

Tags: java, android, eclipse

When I try to clean my projects I am now getting two errors that stops the build process...

Could not delete: D:\myworkspace\library\bin\library.jar.
Could not delete 'D:\myworkspace\google-play-services_lib\bin\google-play-services_lib.jar'.

I am running Eclipse as administrator on my Windows 7 computer.

I have been updating all of my libraries recently in order to use Google Cloud Messaging but I have no idea if this has anything to do with it.

If I delete the jar files manually, then start eclipse and clean it will run ok.  But now I need to do this anytime I want to recompile.

I have googled this error but I can't find anything on it.

Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 2):

When you get the error in Eclipse, try using Process Explorer or similar tool to try to determine what running process is holding on to that file.